# Preventing associated queries on a hasMany model with find

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a model that has several hasMany associations to other models. One thing I have noticed is that when I make a query against the parent table, all of the associated tables are queried as well. For performances sake, I would like to prevent this, as I do not need this data on every call to the parent model.

This is my current parent model:

```
class UserEntity extends UserAgentAppModel {
var $name = 'UserEntity';
var $primaryKey = 'entity_id';
var $actsAs = array('EavEntity');

var $validate = array(
    'user_name'=>array(
        'rule'=>'isUnique',
        'message'=>'This username has already been taken. Please try again'
),
    'user_pass' => array(
        'rule' => array('between', 8, 16),
        'message' => 'Passwords must be between 8 and 16 characters long.')

);

var $hasMany = array(
    'UserEntityVarchar' => array(
        'className' => 'UserEntityVarchar',
        'foreignKey' => 'entity_id',
        'isEav' => 'true'
    ),
    'UserEntityDatetime' => array(
        'className' => 'UserEntityDatetime',
        'foreignKey' => 'entity_id',
        'isEav' => 'true'
    ),
    'UserEntityInteger' => array(
        'className' => 'UserEntityInteger',
        'foreignKey' => 'entity_id',
        'isEav' => 'true'
    ),
    'UserEntityBoolean' => array(
        'className' => 'UserEntityBoolean',
        'foreignKey' => 'entity_id',
        'isEav' => 'true'
    ),
    'UserEntityArray' => array(
        'className' => 'UserEntityArray',
        'foreignKey' => 'entity_id',
        'isEav' => 'true'
    )
);

 );?>
```

This is what I am seeing in the query log. The issue I am seeing is that queries 12-17 always occur when using find. However, I am using a behavior to pull this data from my eav model.

```
1   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `user_entities`      8   8   1
2   SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS WHERE COLLATION_NAME= 'latin1_swedish_ci';     1   1   1
3   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `user_entity_varchars`       4   4   1
4   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `user_entity_datetimes`      4   4   1
5   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `user_entity_integers`       4   4   1
6   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `user_entity_booleans`       4   4   1
7   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `user_entity_arrays`     4   4   1
12  SELECT `UserEntity`.`entity_id`, `UserEntity`.`user_name`, `UserEntity`.`user_pass`, `UserEntity`.`user_status`, `UserEntity`.`user_group`, `UserEntity`.`instance_id`, `UserEntity`.`is_logged_in`, `UserEntity`.`is_visible` FROM `user_entities` AS `UserEntity` WHERE 1 = 1     2   2   0
13  SELECT `UserEntityVarchar`.`value_id`, `UserEntityVarchar`.`attribute_id`, `UserEntityVarchar`.`entity_id`, `UserEntityVarchar`.`value` FROM `user_entity_varchars` AS `UserEntityVarchar` WHERE `UserEntityVarchar`.`entity_id` IN (1, 2)      3   3   0
14  SELECT `UserEntityDatetime`.`value_id`, `UserEntityDatetime`.`attribute_id`, `UserEntityDatetime`.`entity_id`, `UserEntityDatetime`.`value` FROM `user_entity_datetimes` AS `UserEntityDatetime` WHERE `UserEntityDatetime`.`entity_id` IN (1, 2)       0   0   0
15  SELECT `UserEntityInteger`.`value_id`, `UserEntityInteger`.`attribute_id`, `UserEntityInteger`.`entity_id`, `UserEntityInteger`.`value` FROM `user_entity_integers` AS `UserEntityInteger` WHERE `UserEntityInteger`.`entity_id` IN (1, 2)      0   0   0
16  SELECT `UserEntityBoolean`.`value_id`, `UserEntityBoolean`.`attribute_id`, `UserEntityBoolean`.`entity_id`, `UserEntityBoolean`.`value` FROM `user_entity_booleans` AS `UserEntityBoolean` WHERE `UserEntityBoolean`.`entity_id` IN (1, 2)      0   0   0
17  SELECT `UserEntityArray`.`value_id`, `UserEntityArray`.`attribute_id`, `UserEntityArray`.`entity_id`, `UserEntityArray`.`value` FROM `user_entity_arrays` AS `UserEntityArray` WHERE `UserEntityArray`.`entity_id` IN (1, 2)        0   0   0
22  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `eav_attributes`     8   8   1
23  SELECT `EavAttribute`.`attribute_id`, `EavAttribute`.`attribute_code`, `EavAttribute`.`backend_model`, `EavAttribute`.`frontend_input`, `EavAttribute`.`frontend_label`, `EavAttribute`.`is_required`, `EavAttribute`.`is_user_defined`, `EavAttribute`.`is_unique` FROM `eav_attributes` AS  `EavAttribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = 5       1   1   0
24  SELECT `EavAttribute`.`attribute_id`, `EavAttribute`.`attribute_code`, `EavAttribute`.`backend_model`, `EavAttribute`.`frontend_input`, `EavAttribute`.`frontend_label`, `EavAttribute`.`is_required`, `EavAttribute`.`is_user_defined`, `EavAttribute`.`is_unique` FROM `eav_attributes` AS `EavAttribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = 6        1   1   0
25  SELECT `EavAttribute`.`attribute_id`, `EavAttribute`.`attribute_code`, `EavAttribute`.`backend_model`, `EavAttribute`.`frontend_input`, `EavAttribute`.`frontend_label`, `EavAttribute`.`is_required`, `EavAttribute`.`is_user_defined`, `EavAttribute`.`is_unique` FROM `eav_attributes` AS `EavAttribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = 7
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440589/foreign-key-definition-in-cakephp-lazy-loading/7440679#7440679  check this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to pull all the hasMany data in your find query set the value of recursive to -1 like in your controller

```
   $results = $this->Model->find('all', 'recursive' => -1));
```

A better option is to use Containable behavior, this way you can specify which Models to fetch and which not. http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable

Comment: I generally use the Containable behaviour on any model with an association.  Unless you don't care about performance, it's a basic requirement IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Do proper use of ['recursive'](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1063/recursive) and ['unbind model'](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/cornernote/2006/12/10/unbindall) very good functionality of cake to restrict your query upto your useful data.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440589/foreign-key-definition-in-cakephp-lazy-loading/7440679#7440679) how both works's you will get a better idea.